# How to Compare ArrayList Index position with XML Index number which must Show Specific tags Data

Tags: android, arrays, xml, listview, android-studio

I want to compare `ArrayList` Position with My XML index number and After comparing, the Data will show on the Next `Activity`. For example I have an XML which looks like this:

`<Sura index="1" name="abc">  <aya>Data</aya>  <sura index="2" name="cdf"><aya>Data2<aya>`

Now all I want to do is that when I am clicking on(abc) in `ArrayList` and Only that sure data should be come up with who's name is **abc**. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: format the body of post like 'Array List' to 'ArrayList' and remove 'Kindly help'

Comment: Blasanka! Its better to help me regarding my problem! if you can! instead of correcting Grammar and Context.

Comment: If you do not format your question body before posting can be lead to downvotes.